# Some correctly formatted text files not working for conversion to KML files

Tags: java, arrays, file, while-loop

I am currently trying to complete a program where it prompts the user for a data file name and my program then converts it to a KML (Google Earth file). The issue is some files will not be converted into KML even if they are in the correct format. The correct format is a text file has two numbers on each line separated by a space.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class H8_Ruby{
    public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter file name: "); 
    String fileName = input.nextLine();
    Scanner inFile;
    try{
     inFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
     System.out.println("File found: " + fileName);
     try{
        PrintStream outFile = new PrintStream(new File("KMLFile.txt"));
        topPortion(outFile);
        int i = 0;
        while (inFile.hasNextLine()){
           i++;
           String line = inFile.nextLine();
           String[] arr = line.split(" ");
           outFile.println(" <Placemark>");
           outFile.println("   <name>Location " + i + "</name>");
           outFile.println("  <Point>");
           outFile.println("    <coordinates>" + arr[0]+","+arr[1] + ",0</coordinates>");
           outFile.println("  </Point>");
           outFile.println("</Placemark>");
        }
        endPortion(outFile);

     }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
     }
  }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
     System.out.println(fileName + " is not is correct format");

  }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
     System.out.println(fileName + " cannot be found!");
  }              
  }

  public static void topPortion(PrintStream file){
  file.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
  file.println("<kml xmlns=\"http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1\">");
  file.println("<Document>");
  file.println(" <name>Mystery Locations</name>");
  }

  public static void endPortion(PrintStream file){
  file.println("</Document>");
  file.println("</kml>");

  }

  }
```

Can you please tell me if this error has something to do with the array or nextLine function? I've tried looking extensively and can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This part is proberbly your problem:

```
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
}
```

If a file cannot be found (for whatever reason) then your code does nothing. You should instead print out the exception so you know what happened and can then fix it:

```
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Otherwise, try adding some debugging code after each action, and it will become very obvious where your problem is.

For example add `System.out.println("Line contains: " + line);` after you read the `String line = inFile.nextLine();`.

Comment: Yes! it says there is a space in it. Thank you

Comment: have you any idea how I could fix that? If there is a file with a space at the end?